# Combine results from 2 different SELECT request (logical AND)

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in a database :

```
$ SELECT * from image
+----------+------+-----+
| image_id | good | bad |
+----------+------+-----+
|        1 |    2 |   0 |
|        2 |    1 |   0 |
|        3 |    0 |   0 |
|        4 |    1 |   0 |

$ SELECT * from image_tag_map
+----------+--------+-------+
| image_id | tag_id | score |
+----------+--------+-------+
|        1 |      1 |   255 |
|        2 |      1 |   255 |
|        3 |      1 |   255 |
|        4 |      2 |   255 |

SELECT * FROM image_tag_map WHERE tag_id=$tagID and score>=5;
result : 1, 2, 3 (image_id)

SELECT * FROM image WHERE good!=0 ORDER BY good DESC;
result : 1, 2, 4 (image_id)
```

I would like to have 1, 2 as a result. (so a mix between these two commands)
Where the "image_id" is in both places.
I tried with INNER JOIN and such but i can't find something that works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aside from using `JOIN`, you can also use `EXISTS`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    image a
WHERE   a.good <> 0 AND
        EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    image_tag_map b
            WHERE   a.image_id = b.image_id AND
                    tag_id = $tagID AND 
                    score >= 5
        )
ORDER   BY a.good DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d6e3/2)

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` the two tables:

```
SELECT  *
FROM image AS i
INNER JOIN image_tag_map AS m ON i.image_id = m.image_id
WHERE m.tag_id=$tagID and m.score>=5
  AND i.good != 0
ORDER BY i.good DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` should work

```
SELECT * FROM image_tag_map itm 
JOIN image i ON i.image_id = itm.image_id 
WHERE itm.tag_id=$tagID 
AND itm.score>=5
AND i.good!=0
GROUP BY i.image_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
SELECT distinct itm.image_id
FROM image_tag_map itm join
     image i
     on itm.image_id = i.image_id
WHERE item.tag_id=$tagID and item.score>=5 and i.good <> 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT m.* FROM image_tag_map m 
  inner join image i on m.image_id = i.id 
   WHERE tag_id=$tagID and score>=5 and i.good !=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you only need the IDs? There are several ways …

```
SELECT image_id FROM image
WHERE good <> 0
AND image_id IN (
  SELECT image_id FROM image_tag_map
  WHERE tag_id = ? AND score >= 5
)

SELECT image_id FROM image
WHERE good <> 0
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT image_id FROM image_tag_map
  WHERE image_tag_map.image_id = image.image_id
  AND tag_id = ? AND score >= 5
)
```

Using an INNER JOIN should also work:

```
SELECT image_id FROM image i
INNER JOIN image_tag_map itm
ON i.image_id = itm.image_id
WHERE i.good <> 0
AND itm.score >= 5
AND itm.tag_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
select image_id from image where good <> 0 and image_id in 
    (select image_id from FROM image_tag_map WHERE tag_id= ? and score>=5)
    order by good desc
```